# Two gridviews within a gridcontrol - Cannot get focused row handle for the inner grid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

Using DevExpress 10.2 within Visual Studio 2008 with VB.Net I have created a single gridcontrol that contains two different gridviews. The gridviews are related using an `id` column. Basically if there are related details about a row in the first gridview then the user can click on the plus sign to see all the related details. When I have any row on the first gridview I am able to get the focused row. Yet when I have the focus on any of the rows in the second gridview I am unable to get the focused row or the content of the row.

```
gridview2.focusedRowHandle = -2147...
gridview2.getRowCellValue(gridview2.FocusedRowHandle, "id") = Nothing
gridview2.GetFocusedRowCellValue("id") = Nothing
```

Is there any way to get the value in `id` from the focused inner gridview? Or at least figure out the parent row and grab the `id` value from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using is wrong because the DetailViews are separate objects, CLONEs of the detail GridView object assigned to a level.  So, to make the code work, you should use

```
Dim detailRowHandle as integer = CType(gridControl1.FocusedView, ColumnView).FocusedRowHandle
```

For more details, please refer to the [What can cause the properties, methods, and events of a detail grid view to fail?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2158.aspx)

Comment: It is not letting me access the FocusedRowHandle from the gridControl.FocusedView.FocusedRowHandle. It is telling me that "'FocusedRowHandle' is not a member of 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView'"